# Getting error while hashing password using Bcrypt in Python

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt

I am getting error while hashing the pain text password using `Bcrypt` in Python. I am providing the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hash.py", line 3, in <module>
    hashed = hashpw(plaintext_password, gensalt(log_rounds=13))
TypeError: gensalt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_rounds'
```

My code is given below.

```
from bcrypt import hashpw, gensalt
plaintext_password = 'subhra123@'
hashed = hashpw(plaintext_password, gensalt(log_rounds=13))
print hashed
```

Here I need to hash my password.

Comment: well looks like `gensalt()` does not take log_rounds as a parameter? did you look at the docs to see what exactly to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from `log_rounds`, you simply should just use the number. Here is an example:

```
hashed = hashpw(plaintext_password, gensalt(13))
```

**From the official docs:**

> Adjustable Work Factor
>   One of bcrypt’s features is an adjustable logarithmic work factor. To adjust the work factor merely pass the desired number of rounds to bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=12) which defaults to 12):

**Working demo:**

```
import bcrypt
password = b"super secret password"
# Hash a password for the first time, with a certain number of rounds
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(14))
# Check that a unhashed password matches one that has previously been
#   hashed
if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed:
    print("It Matches!")
else:
    print("It Does not Match :(")
```

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/2.0.0) is a link to the docs, where it specifies how to work with this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I thing you want to use `gensalt(13)` or `gensalt(rounds=13)` instead of `gensalt(log_rounds=13)`.